# How to retrieve data passed thru an intent?

Tags: android, string, android-intent, android-notifications

I am sending some data (a String) thru an intent in a notification. However, when I try to receive it in an activity launched by the notification, I don't receive anything. Here is my code. Please help.

This is the code for the notification:

```
int icon=R.drawable.ic_launcher;
                String ticket="Encrypted message";
                long when=System.currentTimeMillis();
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Context context1 =getApplicationContext();
                String expandedText="You've received an encrypted message, click to view";
                String expandedTitle="Encrypted Message";
                Notification notification = new Notification(icon, ticket, when);
                Intent intent1=new Intent(context,Try.class);
                intent1.putExtra("MSG","Jumbo");
                PendingIntent launchIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, intent1,0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context,expandedTitle,expandedText,launchIntent);
                mNotificationManager.notify(1,notification);
```

And here is how I'm receiving it in Try.class :

```
t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dec);
        String d = "";
        Intent I = getIntent();
        d = I.getStringExtra("MSG");
        String text = "This is an example";
        t.setText(d);
```

There is no error - the TextView is set to nothing when I run it

Answer (score 0):

getIntent() won't work there, try to override the onNewIntent method in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Intent intent1=new Intent(context,Try.class);
```

change to

```
Intent intent1=new Intent(YourActivity.this,Try.class);
```

Try it in `onCreate()` method

```
t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dec);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String d;

 if (extras != null) {
      d = extras.getString("MSG");
  }   
t.setText(d);
```

Comment: It is in the `onCreate()` method

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever call
  setResult (Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
in your notifier?  You need that or Android will never restart your "calling" activity.

Comment: No, I didn't. I added it just now and it says that it is not applicable.

Comment: could you elaborate?  Are you getting a syntax error, runtime error, or what?

Answer (score 0):

That should work, try log the value of "d"

```
Log.d("Value of D", d);
```

I think your problem is that your `TextView` t isn't set properly hence not showing the result.

Comment: I set d = "displayText" and executed it - it works well. No problem with the TextView! Just that intent! :(